# Notification appears to be successful even if no data has been added to database

Tags: php, ajax

So I have these codes wherein I want a notification to appear in every event. I want to check if the record exists, then a notification will appear, saying the college already exists. But that doesn't happen tho. I keep on inputting duplicate input, but the notification still says it's successful. Is there a mistake in my code?

> **add-college.php**

```
<?php
function findDuplicate($code) {
    try {
        include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config/db-config.php");

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM colleges WHERE collegecode = ?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $code);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}

try {
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config/db-config.php");

    $code = $_POST['code'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $result = array();

    if (findDuplicate($code)) {
        $result['message'] = 'duplicate';
    }
    else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO colleges(collegecode, collegename) VALUES(?, ?)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $code, $name);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $result['message'] = 'success';
        }
        else {
            $result['message'] = 'error';
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode($result);
}
?>
```

> **script.js**

```
$("#save-new").click(function() {
        var form = $("#add-college");
        var code = $("#code").val();
        var name = $("#name").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                code: code,
                name: name
            },
            url: "../ajax/add-college.php",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.message = "success") {
                    $.notify({
                        // options
                        message: 'College has been added.'
                    },{
                        // settings
                        type: 'success'
                    });
                }
                else if (data.message = "duplicate") {
                    $.notify({
                        // options
                        message: 'College already exists.'
                    },{
                        // settings
                        type: 'warning'
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $.notify({
                        // options
                        message: 'College cannot be added.'
                    },{
                        // settings
                        type: 'error'
                    });
                }

                $("#code").val("");
                $("#name").val("");

                $("#add-new").modal('hide');

                showColleges();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I think is tno bind_param. Bur... bindParam and in the findDuplicate function. what is the 's' param in your select?? And in the INSERT you need 2 params see http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: Your `catch` block is just returning `false` thats almost like ignoring any errors. The idea is you should log the error, and while developing report it to the page so you know that something went wrong and more importantly **what went wrong**

Comment: @RiggsFolly Made a valid point. Please consider that.

Comment: @cmnardi The parameter in my select is in the function parameter `$code`. And I also assigned parameters on my insert statement.

Comment: Show us the Schema for this table

Comment: I tried @RiggsFolly's comment. But it doesn't show any error.

Comment: `mysqli_` does not throw exceptions by default. You have to do as you are doing and text the results of prepare and execute calls

Comment: If neither `collegecode` or `collegename` are set to UNIQUE the duplicate will be allowed and store quite happily. Ltes see your schema

Comment: Have you applied the js fix in the answer below? And made sure that the new js has been loaded to the page (CTRL+F5)

Comment: @RiggsFolly, yes, I did apply the js fix. And the schema for this table is; `id (primary auto_increment), collegecode (unique), collegename`. That's all it is in this table to be honest.

Comment: Thats what I had setup for a test, and the PHP reports an error on attempt to add duplicate

Comment: Run it with the browsers js debugger and set a breakpoint on the `if (data.message == "success") {` line in your js and see what is being returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.message = "success"` this is assignment operation, if you want to compare two string use `==` operator.

So, the correct statement would be for the `if` condition would be `if(data.message == "success")`

Similarly, `if(data.message == "duplicate")`. I am sure you are aware of all this!

Comment: Thank you! I've been coding all day and I think I missed this.

EDIT: unfortunately, still didn't work. Still gets the successful notification after inputting a duplicated data.

Comment: Happens to the best of us!

Comment: Then you have not set the schema to have one or both of these columns as unique

Comment: Let me help you. Can you `console.log(data)` inside success callback?